# Aiopg cursor doesn't return fetchone()

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, aiopg

I am stuck into a problem with aiopg. There are a one problem when i async with engine and try to return a result to endpoint in FastApi. Look down below for my db class.

```
class DBEngine:
    def __init__(self, connection_url: str) -> None:
        self.dsn = connection_url
        self.engine: Optional[Engine] = None

    async def connect(self) -> None:
        self.engine = await create_engine(dsn=self.dsn, maxsize=100)

    @property
    def client(self) -> Engine:
        if self.engine:
            return self.engine
        raise Exception("Not connected to database")

    async def close(self) -> None:
        if self.engine:
            self.engine.close()
            await self.engine.wait_closed()
```

As you can see there is a property, i use it in a code of method of a model class:

```
class Products(Base):
    __tablename__ = "products"
    UUID = sa.Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        unique=True,
        nullable=False,
    )
    product_name = sa.Column(sa.String())

    @classmethod
    async def create_loan(
            cls,
            *,
            product_name: str
    ) -> "Products":
        query = cls.insert_query(
            product_name=product_name
        )

        async with db_engine.client.acquire() as conn:
            cursor = await conn.execute(query)
            return await cursor.fetchone()
```

And finally i'll show an endpoint in fastapi:

```
@routes.post("/api/v1/loans")
async def create_loan(loan: Loan):
    product = await Products.create_loan(product_name=loan.product_name)
    return {"loan_id": product.UUID}
```

ERROR LOG:

```
**Traceback**
...
aiopg.sa.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
```

Please tell me what's wrong, i spent so much time to solve this problem. Feel free to answer, thanks.

Comment: Where is `insert_query` defined? It looks like you are using a query without `RETURNING` so that's the error that you see. Do you only want to return the `load_id`? If yes you can probably change the return statement to `return await cursor.lastrowid`.

Comment: i defined insert_query in declarative base class 
```    
@classmethod
    def insert_query(cls, **values: Any) -> sa.sql.Insert:
        return cls.__table__.insert().values(**values)
```
also i tried to return lastrowid and i got an error - AttributeError: 'ResultProxy' object has no attribute 'lastrowid'

Comment: Yes, aiopg returns a ResultProxy and doesn't support lastrowid. Can you test the following: add `.returning(__table__.c.id)` after `values`(**values)` in `insert_query` and change `return await cursor.fetchone()` to `return await cursor.scaler()` (fetchone doesn't close the cursor).

Comment: i tried that, and error log prints that ResultProxy object has no attribute scaler

Comment: Sorry it needs to be `scalar`!